# Create excel file without library

Tags: php, excel

I using this code:

```
header( "Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel" );
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=liste.xls");

echo "\xEF\xBB\xBF";
```

and I writing my SQL datas in a while loop like this:

```
echo "\n<table><tr><td>".$first[$post_a]."</td>\t<td>".$second[$post_a]."</td>\t<td>".$third[$post_a]."</td>\t</td></tr></table>";
```

When I try to open this created file, excel saying version and type are unmating even so I can open file after this warning on desktop but when I try to open on my phone file can't opening after warning.

Comment: Well, a HTML table doesn't make an Excel file. Faking the MIME type will not work for clients without import filter. So the answer to your question is: no.

Comment: PD of [Which is the best way to generate excel output in PHP?](//stackoverflow.com/q/10595599)

Answer (score 0):

You need to something like this here. Also ignore my logic in for-loop, may want to use your own.

```
    $filename = "export_".date("m-d-Y_hia") . ".csv";
    ob_end_clean();
    $fp = fopen($filename,"w");

    $is_header = true;

    $no_meta_appnd = array('SKU','Name','Publish','Categories','Description');

    foreach ($res as $index => $product){
        $arr = array();

        if($is_header){ // put all the header in array
            foreach ($product as $index => $p){
                if(in_array($index,$no_meta_appnd)){
                    array_push($arr,$index);
                }else{
                    array_push($arr,"Meta: ".$index);
                }
            }
            $is_header = false;
            fputcsv($fp,$arr);  // add headers
            $arr = array();     // empty out array for first row
            foreach ($product as $index => $p){
                array_push($arr,$p);
            }
            fputcsv($fp,$arr);  // add first row after header
        }else{
            foreach ($product as $index => $p){
                array_push($arr,$p);
            }
            fputcsv($fp,$arr);  // rest of the rows
        }
    }
//unserialize();
    fclose($fp);

// download
//    header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$filename);
    header("Content-Type: application/csv; ");
    header('Pragma: no-cache');

    readfile($filename);

// deleting file
    unlink($filename);
    exit();
```

Comment: It's still not an Excel file, technically, but yes it's probably a better approach. You should really explain exactly what your code does when you write an answer

Comment: thank you for answer but i need to xls file format.